# How to Remove anonymous function from DOM elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a mini guessing game with javascript. So basicly, everything works fine at the first time but the second i start having some issue, the items still have the previous status . i tried to remove the function but i dont know how

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="item" >box1</div>
        <div class="item" >box2</div>
        <div class="item" >box3</div>
        <button onclick="startGame()">START</button>
    </div>
    <h1 id="score" style="text-align: center;"></h1>
```

This is my javascript

```
var score =0;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function startGame() {
  alert("game started !!! chose a box")
  var luckNum = getRandomInt(0, 2)
  console.log("this is lucky Num " + luckNum)
  let item = [...document.getElementsByClassName("item")]
  item.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.style.backgroundColor = "white"
  })
  
  item.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.style.cursor = "pointer"
    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(index)
      setColorByIndex(luckNum)
      if(luckNum == index){
        score++;
        alert("You are lucky")
      }else{
        alert("You are unlucky")
      }
      document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Your score"+ score      
    })
  })
}

function setColorByIndex(n) {
  item = document.getElementsByClassName("item")
  for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    if (i == n) {
      item[i].style.backgroundColor = "red"
    } else {
      item[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Move the logic of the handler to a named function that you can reference in both add and remove event listener. It doesn't have to be anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

could overwrite the event every time by directly assigning to it

```
item.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.style.cursor = "pointer"
    item.onclick = () => {
      console.log(index)
      setColorByIndex(luckNum)
      if(luckNum == index){
        score++;
        alert("You are lucky")
      }else{
        alert("You are unlucky")
      }
      document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Your score"+ score      
    };
  })
}
```